# Cx_Oracle OutputTypeHandler for CLOB/NCLOB Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm downloading the data from Oracle database tables using cx_Oracle for Python 7.3.0.
I noticed that whenever I download and process some table containing CLOB/NCLOB data, I experience a huge slowdown.

As indicated in here: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes
I wanted to try to Fetch LOBs as Strings and Bytes.

I think I did everything correctly, but still the code is throwing an error. I also checked changing other types (i.e. numeric ones) with OutputTypeHandler, and also tried to make it on connection level instead of on cursor-level - none of it worked.

**Code**:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_LONG, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_NCLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_LONG, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

ip=1.2.3.4
port=8888
SID='DB1'
dsn_tns=cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip,port,SID)

db=cx_Oracle.connect('USER', 'PASS',dsn_tns)
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.arraysize=500
cursor.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dual").fetchall() #or any other table, of course
db.close()
```

**Error Message**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-bbcd7561378d> in <module>
     16 cursor.arraysize=500
     17 cursor.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler
---> 18 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dual").fetchall()
     19 db.close()
     20 

<ipython-input-106-bbcd7561378d> in OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale)
      2 import csv
      3 def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
----> 4     if defaultType == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
      5         return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_LONG, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
      6     if defaultType == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_NCLOB:

AttributeError: module 'cx_Oracle' has no attribute 'DB_TYPE_CLOB'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx_Oracle 8 added some new constants.

Looking at the [cx_Oracle 7.3 doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/user_guide/lob_data.html) you would use the older names like:

```
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_STRING, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.BLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_BINARY, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
```